# How to count itens in a list using foreach and one condition?

Tags: c#, foreach

I have an 'foreach';

```
 foreach (var item in Model.LstUnidadesGerenciais)
 {
     var count = Model.LstUnidadesGerenciais.Count;
 }
```

I need to get count with one condition like this:

```
 foreach (var item in Model.LstUnidadesGerenciais)
 {
     if (item.Level == 1)
     {
          var count = Model.LstUnidadesGerenciaisWITHCONDITION.Count;
     }
 }
```

I think this is simple, but I'm very begginer in C#

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use LINQ `Where` to select items matching criteria (`Level == 1`):

```
var count = Model.LstUnidadesGerenciais.Where(i => i.Level == 1).Count();
```

Comment: I need to include a reference to use this?

Comment: `System.Linq`, those are extension methods for `IEnumerable`

Comment: Thank you!! Last question. If i need 2 conditions? (i => i.Level == 1 && i=> i.Name == 'walkhard')  this syntax iscorrect?

Comment: Almost, it should look like this: `Where(i => i.Level == 1 && i.Name == "walkhard")`

Comment: On the other hand you may consider using overloaded version of `Count` method as posted by @L.B.

Answer (score 7):

Using Linq

```
var cnt = Model.LstUnidadesGerenciais.Count(x=>x.Level==1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Count method of LINQ -

```
var count = Model.LstUnidadesGerenciais.Count(i => i.Level == 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, you don't need the foreach loop. You can tell, because you never use the `item`, you use the collection instead. I think you need to understand what `foreach` does here:

```
foreach (var item in Model.LstUnidadesGerenciais)
 {
     var count = Model.LstUnidadesGerenciais.Count;
 }
```

`foreach` will iterate over `Model.LstUnidadesGerenciais`. This means that for every `item` in `Model.LstUnidadesGerenciais`, the code inside the curly brackets is executed, with `var item` containing the current item of the collection. [See MSDN for detailed information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx)

As for the second example: You need a variable that contains a number. In the foreach loop you can increment the variable like:

```
int count = 0;

foreach (var item in Model.LstUnidadesGerenciais)
 {
     if (item.Level == 1)
     {
          count++;
     }
 }
```